# NSFetchedResultsController crash when Section index changes

Tags: swift, uitableview, core-data, nsfetchedresultscontroller, sections

I'm writing my app in Swift 3 (converted) in Xcode 8.

NSFetchedResultsController is causing a Serious Application Error for me.

My main table view is sectioned by a text identifier called "yearText" which is being set on any given Event record (NSManagedObject) when the user changes the "Event Date" with a date picker.  When the picker is changed or dismissed, the year is stripped from the date, converted to text, and stored in the Event object.  The managed object context is then saved.

If a date is picked for which there is already a section in existence (i.e. the year "2020") an error is thrown that says:

> [error] error: Serious application error.  An exception was caught from the delegate of NSFetchedResultsController during a call to -controllerDidChangeContent:.  Invalid update: invalid number of rows in section 0.  The number of rows contained in an existing section after the update (2) must be equal to the number of rows contained in that section before the update (1), plus or minus the number of rows inserted or deleted from that section (0 inserted, 0 deleted) and plus or minus the number of rows moved into or out of that section (0 moved in, 0 moved out). with userInfo (null)

As long as the date chosen is not within a year that already has a section named after it, it all works fine.

Here is my relevant code for updating the database and tableview:

```
var fetchedResultsController: NSFetchedResultsController<NSFetchRequestResult> {
    if _fetchedResultsController != nil {
        return _fetchedResultsController!
    }

    // Fetch the default object (Event)
    let fetchRequest = NSFetchRequest<NSFetchRequestResult>()
    let entity = NSEntityDescription.entity(forEntityName: "Event", in: managedObjectContext!)
    fetchRequest.entity = entity

    // Set the batch size to a suitable number.
    fetchRequest.fetchBatchSize = 60

    // Edit the sort key as appropriate.
    let sortDescriptor = NSSortDescriptor(key: "date", ascending: false)

    fetchRequest.sortDescriptors = [sortDescriptor]

    // Edit the section name key path and cache name if appropriate.
    // nil for section name key path means "no sections".
    let aFetchedResultsController = NSFetchedResultsController(fetchRequest: fetchRequest, managedObjectContext: managedObjectContext!, sectionNameKeyPath: "yearText", cacheName: nil)
    aFetchedResultsController.delegate = self
    _fetchedResultsController = aFetchedResultsController

    do {
        try _fetchedResultsController!.performFetch()
    } catch {
         // Implement error handling code here.
         abort()
    }

    return _fetchedResultsController!
}    
var _fetchedResultsController: NSFetchedResultsController<NSFetchRequestResult>?


// MARK: - UITableViewDelegate

    extension EventListViewController: UITableViewDelegate {

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        let cell = tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath) as! EventCell
        cell.isSelected = true
        configureCell(withCell: cell, atIndexPath: indexPath)
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didDeselectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        let cell = tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath) as! EventCell
        cell.isSelected = false
        configureCell(withCell: cell, atIndexPath: indexPath)
    }
}


// MARK: - UITableViewDataSource

extension EventListViewController: UITableViewDataSource {

    func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return fetchedResultsController.sections?.count ?? 0
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        let sectionInfo = fetchedResultsController.sections![section]
        return sectionInfo.numberOfObjects
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "EventCell", for: indexPath) as! EventCell
        configureCell(withCell: cell, atIndexPath: indexPath)
        return cell
    }

    func configureCell(withCell cell: EventCell, atIndexPath indexPath: IndexPath) {
       // bunch of stuff to make the cell pretty and display the data
    }

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, canEditRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> Bool {
    // Return false if you do not want the specified item to be editable.
    return true
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, commit editingStyle: UITableViewCellEditingStyle, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    if editingStyle == .delete {
        let context = fetchedResultsController.managedObjectContext
        context.delete(fetchedResultsController.object(at: indexPath) as! NSManagedObject)
        do {
            try context.save()
        } catch {
                // Replace this implementation with code to handle the error appropriately.
            // abort() causes the application to generate a crash log and terminate. You should not use this function in a shipping application, although it may be useful during development.
            //print("Unresolved error \(error), \(error.userInfo)")
            abort()
        }
    }
}

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, titleForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> String? {
        let sectionInfo = fetchedResultsController.sections![section]
        return sectionInfo.name
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, willDisplayHeaderView view: UIView, forSection section: Int) {
        // make the section header look good
        view.tintColor = kWPPTintColor
        let header = view as! UITableViewHeaderFooterView
        header.textLabel?.textColor = kWPPDarkColor
        header.textLabel?.font = UIFont.preferredFont(forTextStyle: UIFontTextStyle.subheadline)
    }
}


// MARK: - NSFetchedResultsControllerDelegate

extension EventListViewController: NSFetchedResultsControllerDelegate {

    func controllerWillChangeContent(_ controller: NSFetchedResultsController<NSFetchRequestResult>) {
        tableView.beginUpdates()
    }

    func controller(_ controller: NSFetchedResultsController<NSFetchRequestResult>, didChange sectionInfo: NSFetchedResultsSectionInfo, atSectionIndex sectionIndex: Int, for type: NSFetchedResultsChangeType) {
        switch type {
        case .insert:
            tableView.insertSections(IndexSet(integer: sectionIndex), with: .fade)
        case .delete:
            tableView.deleteSections(IndexSet(integer: sectionIndex), with: .fade)
        default:
            return
        }
    }

    func controller(_ controller: NSFetchedResultsController<NSFetchRequestResult>, didChange anObject: Any, at indexPath: IndexPath?, for type: NSFetchedResultsChangeType, newIndexPath: IndexPath?) {
        switch type {
        case .insert:
            tableView.insertRows(at: [newIndexPath!], with: .fade)
        case .delete:
            tableView.deleteRows(at: [indexPath!], with: .fade)
        case .update:
            configureCell(withCell: tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath!)! as! EventCell, atIndexPath: indexPath!)
        case .move:
            tableView.moveRow(at: indexPath!, to: newIndexPath!)
        }
    }

    func controllerDidChangeContent(_ controller: NSFetchedResultsController<NSFetchRequestResult>) {
        tableView.endUpdates()
    }
}
```

I hope you can offer me some suggestions.  Thank you.

EDIT:  Took out some code that was just getting in the way and revised .move to use .moveRow

EDIT 2:  Added FRC generation code.

Comment: Can you show us the code that inserts the event into the context?

Comment: Inserting new events works fine. The editing of a particular event is done by passing the event object and the managed object context to another viewcontroller where the user can edit the event data. When they edit the date, sometimes the FetchedResultsControllerDelegate functions crash, as above. From further testing, it seems that when the user changes the event.date data and the context is saved, controllerWillChangeContent doesn't seem to fire and so tableview.beginUpdates() doesn't fire either. But not all the time. Only when moving the object changes the # of objects in any given section

Comment: your managedObjectContext runs on the main thread, correct?

Comment: I haven't done anything to cause it to do otherwise.  For the most part, I'm using boilerplate code from Apple's own Master-Detail template.  I've even created a new, blank Master-Detail to compare and mine is the same for all the tableView and fetchedResultsController code.

Comment: It would be nice if you can share your project on github

Comment: Unfortunately, that's not possible.

Comment: Please show your FRC creation.

Comment: Added code for FRC creation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I met the same error when I update some properties on my Core Data managed objects.

Here is my controller func:

```
func controller(_ controller: NSFetchedResultsController<NSFetchRequestResult>, didChange anObject: Any, at indexPath: IndexPath?, for type: NSFetchedResultsChangeType, newIndexPath: IndexPath?) {
    switch type {
    case .insert:
        self.tableView.insertRows(at: [newIndexPath!], with: .fade)
    case .delete:
        self.tableView.deleteRows(at: [indexPath!], with: .fade)
    case .update:
        self.tableView.reloadRows(at: [indexPath!], with: .fade)
    case .move:
        self.tableView.insertRows(at: [newIndexPath!], with: .fade)
        self.tableView.deleteRows(at: [indexPath!], with: .fade)
    }
}
```

Before I used newIndexPath for the update case, but I found this will cause some section rows mismatch issue when fetch result controller do some update action. Instead, using indexPath for update case is fine.

Comment: I made this change and it still causes the same error.  Does yours use sections?

Comment: Yes, I use sections. My case is that after I changed the object, it will move from one section to another. So, the old section in "number of rows in section" function will occur the error.

Comment: Just for reminder, in your table view controller, if you handler the data source by core data fetch results controller, you do NOT need to update the data by yourself, any delete or insert command would caused section error.

Comment: I handle the data source through core data fetch.  The code is above and is very straightforward.  I think what's happening is that if I change the data such that the record (entity) now belongs in a new section, something goes wrong.  For example, my sections are years (i.e 2016, 2018) but they don't exist automatically.  When I change one from 2016 to 2020, if 2020 doesn't exist, it has to create a new section.  It's then that I get the error.  If it changes from 2016 to 2018 and both already exist, then I don't think I get the error (have to check again).  newIndexPath didn't help.

Comment: Actually, no, it doesn't matter if it's a new section or not.  By taking one out of section called 2016, that's what causes the error.  It's saying that the number of items before and after the update to 2016 (for example) is incorrect.  I'm really struggling.  I need this to work.

Comment: Does this function look correct?      `func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        let sectionInfo = fetchedResultsController.sections![section]
        return sectionInfo.numberOfObjects
    }`

Comment: I reviewed your code and found in your fetch results controller initialization, the "sectionNameKeyPath" param is "yearText", but the sort param is "date". This is wrong, if you use core data section function, the first sort info must be the same with sectionNameKeyPath, you can use other sort info as the second or third value in sort array. Change it have a try, good luck!

Comment: I just tried.  That didn't work either.  Same error.

Comment: which iOS version did you use? I just saw the similar error on 10.1, I think it's a Core Data bug. When I upgrade to 10.2, no error occur.

Comment: OMG.  After 60 hours of rewrites and troubleshooting, it's an error.  Hands down.  Thank you!